# Resource Not Found Exception when device's power button is pressed

Tags: android

I am writing an app which works fine. There are a lot of activities. Every activity runs in landscape mode. Now suppose that user is seeing an activity and he presses device's power button, now the device is in sleep mode.

But when he again presses the power button the device wakes up, now my app should continue from where user left it but my app just closes down without even a force close message, means user suddenly comes to Home Screen.

In logcat it shows the following error -

```
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start         activity ComponentInfo{com.example.reflexapp/com.example.reflexapp.Login}:     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030023
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030023
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1883)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3028)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1722)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:364)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at com.example.reflexapp.Login.onCreate(Login.java:18)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
01-31 12:22:40.010: E/AndroidRuntime(10591):    ... 11 more
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. In each activity I am doing like this -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.userlogin);
    init();
}
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's in Login.java(line 18) ?

Comment: Its an activity, which has a layout file R.layout.login.

Comment: Are you sure that the R file there is of your own class rather than the generic `android.R`

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem. I was making a mistake, as my app was meant to work only in landscape mode I was putting all my layout xml files in **layout-land** folder. There was nothing in **layout** folder.

But it turned out when device is put to sleep android system tries to bring everything in portrait mode, so it looks for portrait xmls in **layout** folder but gets nothing. Hence it gives Resource not found exception and app exits.

So mental note, even though your app will show only landscape layouts , you must provide portrait xmls in the **layout** folder. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer has also solved my problem. I have had the same problem in my "only landscape" app.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when my Activity was crashing when I pressed the Home or Back button keys. I didn't have the files in the "**layout**" folder because they were only in the "**layout-land**" folder. I simply copied my files from "**layout-land**" to "**layout**" and now the activity doesn't crash when hit the Home key or Back key. This was a bit frustrating at first but everything seems to work fine now.